# How to map nvim recording?

Tags: neovim

My neovim does not show `recording @reg` when I press `q` followed by a character. It is something in my configuration, `nvim --clean` has no issues. I used `redir` and `:verbose map` to no avail.

1. Can one somehow restore the mapping by brute force? For instance, `:map q <Nop>` disables recording, is there a counterpart to enable the map?
2. Is there some intelligent way to troubleshoot this besides commenting out chunks of `init.lua`?

EDIT: I fixed it but the questions remain. If someone encounters the same problem: @adigitoleo's comments helped me realize that recording does work. The issue was that `recording @reg` wasn't visible because of `cmdheight=0` in my `init.lua`.

Comment: neovim  0.9.5 here. `:map q` only shows me some plugin mappings. I suspect the "recording mode" will not show up there, so it won't help you unfortunately. By "does not record" you mean "doesn't print 'recording @reg"? You could check with `:h reg_recording` perhaps

Comment: There are also the RecordingEnter and RecordingLeave autocmd events which might help debugging. Otherwise I'm not sure how to remap it, I don't think the API exposes a `start_recording` kind of function.

Comment: For the record: `:h cmdweight` also documents this: WARNING: `cmdheight=0` is considered experimental. Expect some unwanted behaviour. Some 'shortmess' flags and similar mechanism might fail to take effect, causing unwanted hit-enter prompts. Some informative messages, both from Nvim itself and plugins, will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to debug this other than `:map q`, but this is how you could work around it:

Add the following code to the bottom of `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` (or wherever your main init.lua file is):

```lua
local mode = "n"
local lhs = "q"
local rhs = "q"
local options = {noremap = true}
vim.schedule(function()
    vim.keymap.set(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end)
```

Tested it in my own config and it works.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work for me. Out of curiosity, how did you first create a situation that `:map q` returns `No mapping found` to say that this workaround does the trick?

Comment: Well I can't create a bug that you have without knowing what's the cause of the bug. So I didn't "first create a situation that :map q returns no mapping found". 
Then it must be something more serious and you probably should update your neovim package and all the plugins. And to rule out your config as the source of the bug - outcomminting chunks of the config seems to me the only reasonable way to move on with this.